# In what way can a hacker get sensitive information that's stored on a client side variable?

Tags: javascript, database, security, local-storage

just wondering what ways can a hacker get sensitive information that's store on a client side variable, let's say it's stored in a local storage.
I understand that sensitive data should be store to a server but I want to know the exact reason why it shouldn't be stored on a local storage as much as possible.

I have a authentication that's currently stored on a local storage. So I was wondering why it's safer to store it in the database.

It would be helpful if you can provide a scenario on how can a hacker get the sensitive information on a local storage.

Thank you

Comment: "*It would be helpful if you can provide a scenario on how can a hacker get the sensitive information on a local storage.*" should be obvious but `localStorage.get("superSecretInfo")` works. The client has access to *all* of the information it has. Yes, it's a tautology but it's true. If an attacker can get their own code to be executed on the client, then the attacker also has access to all the data. This could be through XSS, or a browser addon, or whatever that causes your code to work on the same page as attacker code.

Comment: Additionally, think about those millions of public machines, people often use them quite carelessly, and an attacker can be the next user who is going to simply peek the information with the DevTools, the same stands your machine at your office. Yes, that really happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in storing sensitive data locally, as somebody who provides a service you actually need access to the data when information is needed, which is not possible if you stored locally. (Why even bother collecting it otherwise?) Imagine you reinstalled your system. Your client side variable would be lost too in that case and potentially cause you to lose access to your system.

The most important part is that personal data remains encrypted and safe, which you can't guarantee on most people's machines.

Additionally, if somebody means harm, he could send data to your server instead of the client. Imagine you ordered something on Amazon and some scammer could easily inject his own address after each transaction.

As a programmer you always need to assume that your client (even if it is yourself) is completely incapable of securing and safekeeping critical data.

There are probably many more reasons, why you should never store sensitive data locally. (There might still exist some exceptions)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I actually know that storing data locally is not secured. In fact the reason why I'm asking for a scenario is to justify to my team members why it's not safe to store it locally. But I need a solid proof or scenario for them to believe me.